# How to get rid of vscode remote development?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm using VSCode portable for development. Recently, I tried [remote development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq) and get confused between `local-mode` and `remote-mode`. Every times I try to install a new extension, VSCode try to install it in "remote".

I tried to find setting to switch to `local-mode` but there is no setting for that.

I even can't uninstall remote-dev extensions, error messages:

> No remote extension to resolve ssh-remote

Tried to download and extract another new fresh `D:\vscode` but it still stuck in `remote-mode` too. (There may be some setting stored in `$USER` but I can't find out which one is it.)

So, how can I get rid of `remote-development-mode` and back to my "normal VSCode" again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `C:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions`, there you can see all vscode extensions installed. Close your vscode, delete folder like `ms-remote*`, open vscode again. It'll be fine. I've just did it, I got same problem.

Just for safe you can copy the folder elsewhere before remove them.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me, i had no extensions listed as remote.  I disabled subsytem for linux, uninstalled wsl and ubuntu still cant get vs code to get out of remote mode.  Uninstall/re-install did not work either :(

Answer (score 5):

This did it for me.

[https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/07/25/remote-ssh#:~:text=To%20switch%20back%20to%20your,extensions%20on%20your%20remote%20machine](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/07/25/remote-ssh#:%7E:text=To%20switch%20back%20to%20your,extensions%20on%20your%20remote%20machine).

At the bottom of the article:

File > Close Remote Connection.

/Cheers